# Linear Algebra THEOREM 4

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I am a university student studying Linear Algebra. I read the book Linear Algebra by David C. Lay and wonder about d. of Theorem 4

> Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. The following statements are equivalent.
> a. For each $\mathbf{b}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$, the equation $A \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ has a solution.
> b. Each $\mathbf{b}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$.
> c. The columns of $A$ span $\mathbb{R}^m$.
> d. $A$ has a pivot position in every row.

By THEOREM $4$, $A$ has a pivot position in every row.

After reading this, I think $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix like this.

$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

It doesn't have a pivot position in the $2$th row.

Is the THEOREM 4 wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Sources: **Lay, David C.**, *Linear algebra and its applications*. Pearson Education India, 2003.

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Here's more information on [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post, from which I take this quote: *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.*

Comment: How does it follow from that theorem that $A$ has a pivot in every row?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Are you perhaps misreading the statement to be "*Every $m\times n$ matrix necessarily has all of the following statements as being true*"?  That is of course not the case.  There exist matrices who don't have a pivot in every row, such as the example matrix you provide.  What *is* true however is that **if** $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b$ **then** $A$ has a pivot in every row... and similarly if $A$ has a pivot in every row then $Ax=b$ has a solution for every $b$, etc...  That the conditions provided $a,b,c,d$ are such that $a\iff b\iff c\iff d$

Comment: You can prove this by checking that $a\implies b$ and that $b\implies a$ and similarly for each other pair of conditions... or you can prove this in fewer steps by showing that $a\implies b\implies c\implies d\implies a$ having to prove only four implications.  Either all conditions here will be true simultaneously, or all conditions will be false simultaneously

Comment: For your specific example of $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ you will find that condition (a) is false... there exists a matrix $b$ such as $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ such that $Ax=b$ has no solutions... condition (b) is also false... that there exists a matrix $b$ such as $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ such that $b$ is not a linear combination of columns of $A$... that condition (c) is false, the columns of $A$ do not span $\Bbb R^2$... and also that condition (d) is false, that there is a row without a pivot.  No contradiction here.

Comment: I think I misleaded the statement. Thaks for answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misreading theorem 4... It claims that the statements are equivalent, meaning that they are all true or all false. In your example, since the matrix does not have a pivot position in every row, it follows that:

1. The system $Ax =b$ does not have a solution for every $b$;
2. There are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ that are not linear combinations of the columns of $A$.
3. The columns of $A$ do not span $\mathbb{R}^m$.